# Updating data in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, increment

I am trying to see if keyWord already exists in table searchedWords. If it does, then the countr increases by one. If it does not exists in the table, then I used INSERT. The problem is, the keyWord being passed to the site is not stored in the DB. The other BIG problem is that the countr does not add at. Is it because of the if statement? Or is it the while loop?

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$today = date('m-d-Y');
echo $today;
$urltopost = "http://opac.usls.edu.ph/TLCScripts/interpac.dll?Search";
$datatopost = "FormId=0&Config=pac&LimitsId=0&StartIndex=0&SearchField=7&SearchType=1&ItemsPerPage=20&SearchData=$_POST[keyWord]";
$ch = curl_init ($urltopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$returndata = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $returndata;
$con=mysqli_connect("...","...","...","...")or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
$sql= "SELECT * FROM searchedWords";
$result= mysqli_query($con,$sql);


 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{            
        if($row['keyWord']==$_POST[keyWord])
         {
         $upD="UPDATE searchedWords SET countr = countr + 1 WHERE keyWord = '".$row['keyWord']."'";
          while (!mysqli_query($con,$upD))
          {
           die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
           }
         }
        else
        {
         $insertIn="INSERT INTO `searchedWords`( `keyWord`, `countr`) values ('$_POST[keyWord]',1)";
      while (!mysqli_query($con,$insertIn))
          {
          die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
          }
        } 
}
?>
```

Thank you to those who can help me out.

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Never** use string interpolation to accomplish this.

Comment: if($row['keyWord']==$_POST[keyWord]) Do a var_dump on both these variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you making things complex... Try the simple way

```
$KeyWord = $_POST['keyWord']; //Do not forget to sanitize this for security
$sql= "SELECT * FROM searchedWords WHERE keyWord='$KeyWord'";
$result= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$count= mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count) {
$upD="UPDATE searchedWords SET countr = countr + 1 WHERE keyWord = '$keyWord'";
mysqli_query($con,$upD);
} else {
$insertIn="INSERT INTO `searchedWords`( `keyWord`, `countr`) values ('$keyWord',1)";
mysqli_query($con,$insertIn); }
```

Comment: thank your for helping out. This is one of my usual mistakes with coding. Other than forgetting the ;'s and "'s I get lost in loops and if else statements. Minutes later I find myself munching on chips or playing with Photoshop with unfinished work.

Answer (score 0):

It is really bad practice to run sql queries in the loop. Try to use such query to update all existing keywords:

```
    $keyword = htmlspecialchars($_POST['keyWord']);

    UPDATE searchedWords SET countr = countr + 1 WHERE keyWord = '".$keyword."'";
```

No more loops!

And to work more safely and efficient with database take a look on http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I just started with php and I'll sure be reading this link you included. Thank you for the tips and suggestions.

Comment: this link can be useful for you http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-awesome-php-functions-and-snippets